# Verifying Payment in PayPal's iOS SDK necessary?

Tags: ios, paypal, paypal-sandbox

In my app, a user can sign into their paypal account to make a payment using PayPal's SDK.

I create a payment that is submitted via the PayPalPaymentViewController, and in the delegate callback I find the state of the payment is "approved".

However, I am confused because the docs say I need to "verify" this payment. Is this not necessary with the iOS SDK because I do not create any token and my payments come back as approved. And show up as transactions in the Sandbox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Server-to-server calls to PayPal services can help confirm that the payment is authentic, for the expected amount and currency, and that you are the recipient of the payment. If you don’t verify payments, you open yourself to fraud. More information on verifying a mSDK payment can be found [here](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/integration/mobile/verify-mobile-payment/).

Comment: Got it: so after the MSDK returns me the completedPayment ID via the didCompletePayment delegate callback, I use the payment-id along with my bearer access token to verify the payment. Thanks! The link you provided was the one I needed.